# Cannot run tomcat websocket examples remotely

Tags: tomcat, websocket, tomcat7

I can run all the websocket examples as long as my browser runs on the same machine as tomcat is running on. But once I try to connect from a remote machine the connection always fails with the error below in my Firebug console. Is there an extra bit of security configuration required to run this? I am using 7.052

```
"NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://remote-host:8080/examples/websocket/chat"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a proxy configured on my browser and that was what was blocking the access